# API call won't happen in ngrx-angular6

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am new to ngrx.API call won't happen in ngrx-angular6. i have tried everything. i cant find where i am wrong. whole day wasted here.:(

In Effects i have called a service and getting observable

```js
@Effect()
  isFileFeed$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch(LandingActionTypes.LoadIsFileFeed, {
    run: (action: LoadFileFeed, state: LandingState) => {
      const url = `www.sample.com`;
        this.service.apiRequest(url).pipe(
          map(function(status){
            new LoadFileSuccess(status);
          }),
          catchError(err => of(new LoadFileError(err.Description)))
        );
    },

    onError: (action: LoadFileFeed, error) => {
      console.error('Error', error);
      return new LoadFileError(error);
    }
  });
```

In Service i have used pipe along with tap. if i call subscribe directly API call Invokes. but here it wont call any API. am also verified in the network tab also.

```js
apiRequest(url){
return this.http.get<any>(url)
        .pipe(tap(response =>
            this.log(`Service :api success: ${url}`);
          ),
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}
```

here is my code in selector

```js
const getLandingState = createFeatureSelector<LandingState>('landing');

const getFileEnableStatus = createSelector(
  getLandingState,
  (state: LandingState) => state.isFileFeedEnabled
);
```

and i have consumed my observable through subscribe in my component like below.

```js
    this.landingPageStore.pipe(select(landingSelector.landingQuery.getFileEnableStatus)).subscribe(res=>{
      this.isFileEnabled = res;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your effect isn't firing at all, it's possible that you never registered it in the imports section of your @NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    // Some imports
    EffectsModule.forRoot([MyEffectClass])
  ]
})
```

Another possibility is your lack of a returning the service's observable, and the function within the map function, you might have more luck with the following:

```
return this.service.apiRequest(url).pipe(
  map((status: any) => {
    return new LoadFileSuccess(status)
  }
```

Be sure that if you wrap the arrow function in curly braces that you explicitly add the return keyword, otherwise things will not work as expected.